# Google maps api v2 - failure error

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps-android-api-2

I work in team on that run the same application (we work with eclipse).

When i run google maps i get this error:

> > 01-29 13:26:08.445: W/ResourceType(404): getEntry failing because entryIndex 13 is beyond type entryCount 3
>
> 01-29 13:26:08.445: W/ResourceType(404): Failure getting entry for
>   0x7f0c000d (t=11 e=13) in package 0 (error -2147483647)
>
> 01-29 13:26:08.445: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(404): The Google Play
>   services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to
>   ensure that the resources are included.

In some times i get  the error :

> 01-29 16:16:28.795: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(31102): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
>   01-29 16:17:16.255: E/Google Maps Android API(31102): Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start for how to correctly set up the map.
>   01-29 16:17:16.260: E/Google Maps Android API(31102): Ensure that the following correspond to what is in the API Console: Package Name: com.applicat.meuchedet, API Key: AIzaSyAPf9_FQjkmARqhS_fbW3SdXXbLwzQXPwk, Certificate Fingerprint: 1BE3F51C82C911E280FD2808F6741CFA80F53465

This strange behavior it's occurred only me!!

The other co-workers that work on the same project(svn) get Google Maps.

I try all the answers that i found in stackoverflow.. it's doesn't work

Also i try to run the project that sit at co-worker workspace.
It's doesn't work!!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error.

In my case it was related to the call to

```
map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

in the case of use of the default map provider.

The solution was in my case to code a trivial location source and pass it with

```
map.setLocationSource(...);
```

Just to check if it is the same, try to comment out the line with setMyLocationEnabled (if you have one).

Comment: I dont think that this the problem. because this code is project team code and ti the other co-workers is run..

Answer (score 0):

Try following steps,

1. Try to install `Google Play services` in `android SDK manager`
2. Enable the `Google Maps Android API v2` service in the `Google API's console`
3. Try to add (or) refer the `Google Play lib` from the project

then your map will run.

Comment: I try all this. I install the last version from android SDK manager. I also re-install the application from the device.

Comment: are u running in device or in emulator